# log loss should be easy to calculate but it is not

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Why it is not working:

```
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
y_true = [0, 0, 0, 0]
y_pred = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
log_loss(y_true, y_pred, eps=1e-15)
```

```
Error: ValueError: Unknown label type: ((0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5),)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`log_loss`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html) does not know (cannot infer) what labels there are since there's just one unique label in your example.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss

y_true = [0] * 4
y_pred = [0.5] * 4
log_loss(y_true, y_pred, labels=[0, 1]) # 0.6931471805599453
```

alternatively labels can be inferred if there is more than one unique label in `y_true`:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss

y_true = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
y_pred = [0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.99]
log_loss(y_true, y_pred) # 0.46093345183967405
```